# ¿Se puede testear una variable en PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

llevo un par de días que estoy trabajando con TDD con PHP y PHPUnit.
Actualmente estoy probando de hacer una clase coche (Car) para empezar con algo básico, pero he llegado al punto en el que quiero añadir variables a la clase y no encuentro ninguna aserción para el test de Car (CarTest) que compruebe si hay una variable y/o esta tiene algún dato asignado.

Aquí os dejo la clase que estoy intentando hacer a partir de TDD:

```
class Car{
    public $Oil = false;
}
```

Y aquí el fichero de Tests de PHPUnit:

```
class CarTest extends TestCase{
    public function testFileExists(){
        $this->assertFileExists("Car.php");
    }
    public function testCarHaveOilAttribute(){
        $Oil = false;
        $this->assertClassHasAttribute('Oil', "Car");
    }
}
```

¡Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

El test que buscas es este:

```
public function testCarHaveOilAttribute(){
    $car = new Car();

    $this->assertFalse($car->Oil);
}
```

Ten también en cuenta varias cosas:

- `testFileExists()` no tendría que hacerte falta. Si eres capaz de instanciar la clase `Car` ya se da por hecho que el fichero está.
- las variables se suelen nombrar como convención en camelcase, pero empezando en minúscula para distinguir de las clases/interfaces que si que empiezan con mayúscula -> `$oil`